# pygame - How to write text onto a specific location? Also, how to use coordinates

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3

I've been trawling around and I can't really find any good resources on how to write text? I've tried using the rendering command for text but it isn't working for me.

Also, whilst you're here; is there an 'overlay' type of thing where you can see exactly where coordinates are? I can't really figure out how this whole coordinate system works apart from using trial and error each time I use coordinates to pinpoint an area...

Many thanks,

Comment: Did you read http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/games2.html? Did it help?

Comment: If you're still having issues why not update your question with some more info?  You had marked an answer and then removed it.

Comment: Sorry, think I accidentally mis-clicked the answer button on your answer. It's the answer again now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendering a font is pretty straight forward!

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 

# Initialize the font system and create the font and font renderer
pygame.font.init()
default_font = pygame.font.get_default_font()
font_renderer = pygame.font.Font(default_font, size)

# To create a surface containing `Some Text`
label = font_renderer.render(
    "Some Text",   # The font to render
    1,             # With anti aliasing
    (255,255,255)) # RGB Color
```

This returns a surface that can be blit to another surface.  This surface also contains a Rect with the dimensions of said font.

```
# To apply this surface to another you can do the following
another_surface.blit(
    label,  # The text to render
    (0,0))  # Where on the destination surface to render said font
```

Now the coordinate system is pretty straight forward,

You create your screen like so

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * 
screen_dimensions = width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_dimensions)
```

In pygame this will create a screen like so

```
       800    
    -----------
    -         -
600 -         -
    -         -
    -----------
```

The upper left-most corner is the coordinates `0,0` and the bottom right-most corner is `800,600`

If you wanted to blit your font in the upper left corner with a padding of 5px you could do the following:

```
# Using the label created above
screen.blit(label, (5, 5))
```

I wrote a game of life clone in PyGame and you can see the source https://github.com/MikeMcMahon/GameOfLife and figure out exactly how I use the fonts to render them.

As for an overlay to see the exact coordinates of things.  You could easily do that by capturing the mouse position `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` and pushing that to a label you render on the surface.

Answer (score 3):

```py
surf = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

...

# get font object
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 12, bold=True)    

# render a given font into an image
img = font.render('Text to write', True,
                  pygame.Color(FONT_FG_COLOR),
                  pygame.Color(FONT_BG_COLOR))

# and finally put it onto the surface.
# the code below centres text image
surf.blit(img, ((surf.get_width() - img.get_width())/2,
                (surf.get_height() - img.get_height())/2))
```

Answer (score 2):

here is some more help: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapters/

and for your specific questions read this: http://inventwithpython.com/pygame/chapter2.html

scroll down to "Pixel Coordinates" to learn about coordinate system in pygames

scroll down further in chapter2 to learn about fonts and how to render them.